# Semantic-UI sidebar with fixed top menu

Tags: javascript, user-interface, semantic-ui

Semantic-UI forewarns on its [sidebar page](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/usage) that "Fixed position content may have issues changing its position when a sidebar appears." It then provides two possible solutions to the problem.

Surprisingly, on that very same page and throughout the site, Semantic-UI's website uses a fixed top menu that adjusts just fine when the left sidebar is triggered.

I want to simply create a fixed top menu like the one Semantic-UI's site uses that adjusts properly when the sidebar is opened. However, this is proving frustratingly difficult, as neither of the two proposed solutions work. I've inspected the markup, css, and javascript but can't figure out how he went from the code Semantic-UI provides to a working fixed top menu that adjusts properly when the sidebar is opened.

Any thoughts or direction? Using Semantic-UI how do you create a fixed top menu that adjusts properly when a sidebar is opened?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> Using Fixed Content Any fixed position content that should move with
>   page content when your sidebar is visible, should receive the class
>   name fixed and exist as a sibling element to your sidebar.
>
> Fixed content that is not included adjacent to your pusher will lose
>   its positioning when a sidebar is shown.

```
<div class="ui left vertical inverted labeled icon sidebar menu">
</div>
<div class="ui fixed inverted main menu">
</div>
```

Comment: correct answer but need more detailed explanation: the important part is that the menu (fixed element) should be **direct sibling** of the sidebar `<Sidebar/><Menu fixed/><Sidebar.Pusher/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Left Sidebar -->
<div class="ui visible inverted left vertical sidebar menu">
    <a class="item">Home    </a>
    <a class="item">Page 1</a>
    <a class="item">Page 2</a>
</div>

<!-- Top Fixed Menu -->
<div class="ui top fixed menu">
    <a class="item menu-trigger">Menu</a>
    <a class="item">Page 1</a>
    <a class="item">Page 2</a>
</div>

<div class="pusher">
    <!-- Page Content Here-->
    <div class="ui basic segment">
        <h3 class="ui header">Hello there</h3>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to put the code above inside the "body" tag and including the css & js files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'exclusive' setting to display multiple sidebars that play nicely with each other.

$('.your-shared-sidebar-class').sidebar('setting','exclusive',false).sidebar('show');