# Semantic UI - Sidebar breaking Fixed Menu in React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to add a Semantic UI sidebar to my app while at the same time keeping a fixed bottom menu. It says on the [documentation page](http://1.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/usage) that

> Any fixed position content that should move with page content when your sidebar is visible, should receive the class name fixed and exist as a sibling element to your sidebar.

They also provide an example:

```
<!--body-->
  <div class="ui sidebar">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="ui top fixed menu">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    Your site's actual content
  </div>
<!--/body-->
```

I am trying to follow the example, so I made my bottom menu a sibling of the sidebar. However, despite being a sibling of the sidebar, the bottom menu still break and instead of keeping a fixed position it scrolls with the page. If I comment out the sidebar from my code, then the bottom menu works fine, keeping the fixed position. Below is my component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Localize the selector instead of having jQuery search globally
    var rootNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    // Initialize the sidebar
    $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
      context: $(rootNode)
    });
  }

  openSidebar() {
    var rootNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ui left vertical thin menu sidebar"></div>
        <div className="pusher">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className="ui bottom fixed icon menu"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806034/semantic-ui-sidebar-with-fixed-top-menu) but none of the answers helps with my problem. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Instead of making the components siblings, I added my bottom fixed menu one level higher in the view hierarchy and changed the root node accordingly. I am not sure why it didn't work the way it was described in the docs so would appreciate if someone could clarify.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Localize the selector instead of having jQuery search globally
    var rootNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myref);
    // Initialize the sidebar
    $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
      context: $(rootNode)
    });
  }

  openSidebar() {
    var rootNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myrefx);
    $(rootNode).find('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ui bottom fixed icon menu"></div>
        <div ref="myref">
          <div className="ui left vertical thin menu sidebar"></div>
          <div style={{paddingBottom: "90px"}} className="pusher">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```